# After setting up my own domain on Github Pages, I get an InvalidDNSError

Tags: github, github-pages

**Phenomena**

After setting up my own domain on Github Pages, I get an InvalidDNSError.
The following message will appear

"Both [www.example.work](http://www.example.work) and its alternate name are improperly configured
Domain's DNS record could not be retrieved. For more information, see Learn more (InvalidDNSError). We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing to username.github.io."

**Expected value**

I want to publish a website using github pages on my own domain.

Answer (score 5):

From your question, I assume that you are added `www.example.work` as custom domain in the github pages section and you might be missed the DNS settings part.

After adding custom domain in github pages, you need to setup a CNAME and 4 A record under the DNS settings of you custom domain.

[image]

you can find the detailed steps [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) in the official documentation of github.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. After double checking the DNS with `dig` and continuing to get the same error, I removed the custom DNS on the GitHub Pages Settings form (using the "Remove" button) and then re-added it. That cleared the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your domain DNS to CNAME  and try again.
[image]

as a Name you type www and in the target URL form, GitHub link.

Comment: I tried to set up DNS and CNAME as you suggested, but it didn't work.

Comment: Leave it for an hour and check again, it's need some time to set up the DNS.If its the message same?

Comment: The same message will appear.